# Force Spring Data JPA to fire INSERT query without SELECT for detached entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate in which I am operating on the detached entity. So when I save the detached entity hibernated internally call the `merge` method which executes first `SELECT` statement and then the `INSERT` statement. (The entity is not in the DB but for other reason the entity is in detached state)

```java
custRepository.save(billingInfo);
```

Lets say billingInfo is detached entity, when spring jpa save method is called, it will trigger `merge` method internally resulting `SELECT` statement execution first and then `INSERT` statement.

Is there is a way to tell hibernate to execute only the `INSERT` query for the detached entity?

I am already implementing the `Persistable` interface which I am managing the state of the entity.

Below is the entity

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name= "BLI_INFO")
public class BillingInfo implements Persistable<long> {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "BLI_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "BLI_ID_SEQ", name = "id_gen", allocationSize = 1)
    private long billingId;

    ...
    // rest of the fields
    ...

    @Transient
    private boolean isNew = false;

    @PrePersist
    @PostLoad
    void markNotNew() {
        this.isNew = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew(){
       return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use JDBC for sane database access? Use JPA directly since it has it? Stop worrying and learn to live to 5 levels of abstraction? Write your own method with a custom query.

Comment: AFAIK it fires SELECT only, if we pass an entity with an id. F. e., if I have on the front end a table with entities, where some are added right now and some are only updated, then JPA will fire for the updated entites SELECT, then UPDATE, for the new ones then INSERT.